# Should I update someone else's obsolete answer?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I just ran across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549504/937377) regarding browser support for unprefixed CSS linear gradients. As a comment notes, the answer is very obsolete. Should I edit the answer to correct it, in the process entirely reversing what the answerer had originally said?

Regarding suggested dupe: That question is regarding a minor edit which wouldn't go against the intention of the original answerer. The change I'm asking about would be a major edit, as it would completely reverse what the answer originally said.

Comment: Why not write your own answer?

Comment: @RobertLongson There's already an upvoted [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26593134/937377). I guess that answers my question, then? Downvote and move on?

Comment: [How to deal with obsolete answers?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/11705)

Comment: No, definitely don't *downvote* the answer! (I mean, you can vote however you want, but *I* wouldn't downvote it.) It was correct when it was posted. Just fix the darn thing. If you're smart enough to see the problem, you're smart enough to fix it.

Comment: @CodyGray Certainly, I'm smart enough to fix it. But per your linked thread, the highest-voted answer by Shog9 uses phrases like "fixing a minor bug / edge-case" and "preserv[ing] the intent of the author." Arguably, I couldn't do either of those things if I corrected this answer.

Comment: It *is* an edge case—time marched on and edged the original answer into obsolescence. It also very much preserves the intent of the original author—the answer was correct when he posted it, and there's no reason to assume that he intended the answer to become obsolete and unhelpful in the future. You could edit it judiciously to say that "As of xxx date/version/browser, this is now supported…blah blah blah" if that made you feel better.

Comment: @CodyGray Point taken. I'll go ahead and correct the answer.